# Is there another way to do this? I used align*

Tags: align

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Calculate:

\begin{align*}
(a) &\,\: +(-31)+(-14)=  & \quad(d) &\,\: -(-12)-(+9)=  & \quad(g) &\,\: (-11)\cdot(+18)=  & \quad(j) &\,\: (-18):(+9)=\;\: \\   
(b) &\,\: +(+44)+(-28)= & \quad(e) &\,\: -(-21)-(-15)= & \quad(h) &\,\: (-13)\cdot(-17)=  & \quad(k) &\,\: (-39):(-3)=\;\:\\
(c) &\,\: -(-26)+(-54)= & \quad(f) &\,\: +(+22)-(+10)= & \quad(i) &\,\: (+27)\cdot(-19)=  & \quad(l) &\,\: (+52):(-4)=\;\:
\end{align*}

\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

I want it to look like this:

> I want the text to have this format and a 1 instead of 2. I inserted
> several spaces (; : \ quad) to try to adjust the text.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Note that you want to highlight your code and then click `{}` in order to have it format properly.  You've also not given the code that creates that image (specifically, nothing you have here would cause `\item` to give 2).  The parts that you've left out might not be important, but then again, they could be.  What are you intending with the `,:`?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution that employs the [tasks](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tasks) package and its `tasks` environment. Observe that this setup (a) generates horizontal (rather than vertical) lists and (b) allows the content of each task to be rendered in math mode automatically.

Incidentally, you may want to use `\div` rather than `:` to indicate division.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % make sure text block is wide enough 
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
Calcule:
\begin{tasks}[label=(\alph*),label-width=2em,item-format=\ensuremath](4)
    % see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595332/5001
\task +(-31)+(-14)
\task -(-12)-(+9)
\task (-11)\cdot(+18)
\task (-18)\div(+9)
\task +(+44)+(-28)
\task -(-21)-(-15)
\task (-13)\cdot(-17)
\task (-39)\div(-3)
\task -(-26)+(-54)
\task +(+22)-(+10)
\task (+27)\cdot(-19)
\task (+52)\div(-4)
\end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX-SE @etmat. I think a method using `enumitem` and a column environment such as `multicol` do a much easier job. The main point is to avoid insert any kind of manual enumeration.

Please, notice I add `geometry` in order to display the equations as in your example. I also removed the `ams`-family packages since they were not necessary to this particular example.

You may use any environment/command to access math mode. In the example below I used `math` em `$$`since they achieve the same results.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Calculate:
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
    \begin{multicols}{4}
      \item
      \begin{math}
        +(-31)+(-14)=
      \end{math}
      \item
      \begin{math}
        +(+44)+(-28)=
      \end{math}
      \item
      \begin{math}
        -(-26)+(-54)=
      \end{math}

      % Changing method
      \item $-(-12)-(+9)=$
      \item $-(-21)-(-15)=$
      \item $+(+22)-(+10)=$
  
      \item $(-11)\cdot(+18)= $
      \item $(-13)\cdot(-17)= $
      \item $(+27)\cdot(-19)= $
  
      \item $(-18):(+9)=$
      \item $(-39):(-3)=$
      \item $(+52):(-4)=$
    \end{multicols}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an elegant solution! In theory, one could have simply used a tabular, which, however, would have led to manually assigning the alphanumeric enumeration.